# Wordpress get_option in External PHP file

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have created a plugin that adds products programatically to WooCommerce.  The plugin is working great, but now I need to make a cron job that runs every 5 minutes to update the inventory.

I have the script all written but I need to include calls to get_option() in this php file to get certain plugin values that the user has entered.  However, I can't just include `get_option()` in this file because it is outside of the Wordpress core.  So my thought would be to put in `require( 'path/to/wp-load.php' );` which I know you aren't really supposed to do.  Anyway it fixes the issue if you hit the page via a web browser request.  However the cron job fails the moment that this file is included because somewhere with wp-load.php it is sending HTTP_Header requests.

Any thoughts or solutions? I tried to add  `define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);` right above the requiring of wp-load.php but it is still causing the cron job to fail.

Long winded I know, but how do you include `get_option()` requests inside of a external PHP script that will be accessed via a PHP cron job.

Thanks much.

Comment: You don't want to do it that way.  Use the built-in WP Cron system.  If you need a reliable 5 minute cron job, then you actually set up a cron job that triggers the built-in WP cron system: [Schedule Events Using WP Cron](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/schedule-events-using-wordpress-cron/)

Comment: I suppose for whatever reason it isnt possible to put this file inside the wordpress folder structure?

Comment: @Theavonguy - that's not the way to do it.  I've been down this road (lots of experience).  You CAN "bootstrap" WP without running the front-end, but that is NOT the proper way to hook / trigger cron jobs for WP plugins.

Comment: @cale_b I don't agree, WP cron system is not reliable for this kind of jobs as it is dependant to if someone visit your website every 5min. For this kind of case including _wp-load.php_ to get the WP core is the right way to go.

Comment: @vard - That **used to be** my concern also, however you can set up a true cron job to trigger the wp_cron.  Read the article I linked, that is discussed.

Comment: @cale_b Ah, I see what you mean. I guess that's a possible way to go indeed.

Comment: @caleb_b can you look at the comment that I made below on vard's post about the cron job.  I think I have it set up correctly but it isn't displaying anything when I hit it in the browser like I thought it would/should?

Answer (score 3):

#### The quick and easy way

The problem is probably that you try to include *wp-load.php* from a wrong path. In a CLI environment, the path would not be the same as when you do an HTTP request to the file. So with this you should fixed your issue:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../wp-config.php');
```

#### The proper but longer way

Based on cale_b comments and [this article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/schedule-events-using-wordpress-cron/) he linked, there is a much proper way to go by doing a [Wordpress Cron job](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event).

First in your plugin add a function that will contain the code needed to be executed, let's call it `my_cron_job()`. You can eventually just include the script you already wrote in this function. Then add the following to schedule the execution of this every 5min:

```
// Define a new interval (5 minutes)
add_filter('cron_schedules', 'fively_interval');
function fively_interval($interval) {
    $interval['fively'] = array('interval' => 5*60, 'display' => 'Once 5 minutes');
    return $interval;
}

// Register the hook on plugin activation
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_cron_job_activation');
add_action('my_cron_event', 'my_cron_job');
function my_cron_job_activation() {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'fively', 'my_cron_event');
}

// Unregister the hook on plugin deactivation
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_cron_job_deactivation' );
function my_cron_job_deactivation(){
  wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'my_cron_event' );
}
```

Then set up your cron to execute *wp-cron.php* every 5 minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * php-cli -f [path to your WP]/wp-cron.php
```

---

#### Update

First when choosing the option of executing *wp-cron.php* with a server cron you should disable the default WP Cron behaviour (execution of cron through web visits):

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

Secondly, as for your question about WP Cron reliability I see a potential flaw indeed. I'm not 100% sure of that, but I think it is possible that `wp_schedule_event` get desynchronized with the server cron, as the job get executed only if the interval is past. As it will be re-scheduled depending of the execution time of the script which is ***slightly*** different with the server cron time.

For example:

```
00:00:00:000    Server cron execute wp-cron.php
00:00:00:100    The job can be executed, so let it run
00:00:00:200    Wordpress finished to execute the job - it schedule the event in 5min
00:05:00:000    Server cron execute wp-cron.php
00:05:00:100    The job is planned for 00:05:00:200, no execution !
00:10:00:000    Server cron execute wp-cron.php
00:10:00:100    The job is executed
```

***That's theory of course***, maybe this is not accurate. I suggest doing some test and see how it behave. If it indeed behave like I think it did, I suggest as easy workaround to change the `wp_schedule_event` to a lower interval - 4min for example.

```
add_filter('cron_schedules', 'fourly_interval');
function fourly_interval($interval) {
    $interval['fourly'] = array('interval' => 4*60, 'display' => 'Once 4 minutes');
    return $interval;
}
```

So we'll have the following:

```
00:00:00:000    Server cron execute wp-cron.php
00:00:00:100    The job can be executed, so let it run
00:00:00:200    Wordpress finished to execute the job - it schedule the event in 4min
00:05:00:000    Server cron execute wp-cron.php
00:05:00:100    The job is planned for 00:04:00:200, so let it run!
00:10:00:000    Server cron execute wp-cron.php
00:00:00:200    Wordpress finished to execute the job - it schedule the event in 4min
00:10:00:100    The job is executed (planned for 00:09:00:200)
```

With the default WP Cron behaviour disabled it should work flawlessly.

Comment: I'm now trying to set the cron up through wp_cron.  I changed the cron path in my hosting environment to hit wp-cron.php every 5 min.  And I added this code http://puu.sh/lWFWm/e757147b17.png.  When I hit the wp-cron.php in the browser should it be printing out yes?

Comment: Also I did have `chdir(dirname(__FILE__));

require( '../../../wp-load.php' );` in the top of that cron file.  Still investigating why it didn't work.

Comment: Ok I figured out why the original cron job wasn't working in my wp-config.php file I had this code `define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);` when I hardcode those values in there the original cron starts working.  The one that was referencing wp-load.php.  But I'm still interested in making it work with the wp-cron.php so let me know on my other comments.  Thanks much.

Comment: Ok I figured out how to what was wrong with my code above my function had to be called `my_cron_job()` like you said and I for some reason named it `my_cron_event()`  So now all I have to do is set my cron job to hit wp-cron.php every 5 minutes?  My cron will send me a results email.  Will there be any "results" from the cron like text that I have printed in my cron job or anything or is that not returned?

Comment: Well I suggest to encapsulate your code with an [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) to capture everything that is being echo during your cron, and send this buffer result by mail.

Comment: At the moment I'm torn with whether or not to use the wp-load method or to use the wp-cron method.  Both of them are working, but for some reason wp-cron feels less efficient because there are like 5-6 cron jobs that are running through wp-cron (from WooCommerce).  So if I hit wp-cron.php with my cron job wouldn't that cause all of those other jobs to run?  Also is it full proof that wp-cron.php will run the script that I put in every 5 min if that's how often I hit that file?

Comment: Well the other jobs are not a problem, as they're probably not planned to run every 5min only your job will run most of the time. As for your other question, it's a very good one. I updated my question to bring some explanations about that.