# WP Cron Timeout

Tags: php, wordpress

Based on a recent some advice from this post [Wordpress get_option in External PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293363/wordpress-get-option-in-external-php-file) I switched a PHP cron job that I had running to update some inventory in Wordpress/WooCommerce to a native wp-cron job.  Everything is working fine my only concern is if the wp-cron will timeout.  When I had this PHP job running on a rackspace server the PHP cron timeout was 15 minutes.

While I don't anticipate it taking very long it might. I'm just wondering if a wp-cron job has a timeout and if so what that timeout is?

Thanks much.

Comment: If you follow the advice through and you trigger the wp-cron through the crond on the server you don't have to worry about timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the execution time, Here are the reference to increase
https://davidwalsh.name/increase-php-script-execution-time-limit-ini_set.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors#Maximum_execution_time_exceeded

Hope it will be helpful !!